# Using RabbitMQ docker image

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I started a rabbitmq docker container as described here https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/

```
$ sudo docker run -d --hostname myrabbit --name rabbit rabbitmq:3
```

Then I got the docker container's IP like so:

```
$ sudo docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' rabbit
172.17.0.2
```

Then try to connect to rabbit with telnet like so:

```
$ telnet 172.17.0.2 4369
```

But I get this output:

```
Trying 172.17.0.2...
telnet: connect to address 172.17.0.2: Network is unreachable
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I tried port 5672 also with the same result.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't executing `docker run ...` correctly.  I needed to use the `-p` option like so:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Then I can point my browser to http://localhost:15672 and everything works.